# vite bundle skeleton ui -- safelisting skeleton-tailwind utility classes

Tags: vite, svelte, postcss, skeleton-ui, purgecss

I am trying to use SkeletonUI for my Svelte project (without sveltekit). I create a bundle using Vite for all the SkeletonUI  tailwind directives (badge, variant-filled), and skeletonUI svelte components (Avatar, AppBar) etc.
The svelte components are rendered properly but the skeleton tailwind directives are not present in the bundle.
I tried tinkering with safelist options with the purgeCss but that doesn't seem to work.
The complete working example is [here](https://github.com/Monallabs/Svelte-Tailwind-Skeleton-Bundler-Debug).

- [Sample SkeletonUI component and utilty classes](https://github.com/Monallabs/Svelte-Tailwind-Skeleton-Bundler-Debug/blob/main/src/SkeletonUI.svelte)
- [tailwind.config.ts](https://github.com/Monallabs/Svelte-Tailwind-Skeleton-Bundler-Debug/blob/main/tailwind.config.ts)

The vite.config.ts looks as follows:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';
import { purgeCss } from 'vite-plugin-tailwind-purgecss';

import postcss from './postcss.config.ts';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
   plugins: [svelte(),
   purgeCss({
            safelist: ['badge', 'btn-icon', 'variant-filled', 'fa-solid', 'fa-skull'],
        }
        )
   ],
   css: { postcss

},
   build: {
    lib: {
      entry: 'src/main.ts', // Specify the entry file for the bundle
      name: 'jpComponentBuilder', // Specify the global variable name for the bundle
      formats:['iife'],
      fileName: 'bundle', // Specify the name of the bundle file
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
      },
    },
  },
  
  });
```

Not sure what am I missing.

[index_bundle.html](https://github.com/Monallabs/Svelte-Tailwind-Skeleton-Bundler-Debug/blob/main/index_bundle.html) is the runner which loads the bundle. The [abc.js](https://github.com/Monallabs/Svelte-Tailwind-Skeleton-Bundler-Debug/blob/main/abc.js) creates the Skeleton component but no skeleton utility classes are working. Tailwind utility classes and skeleton svelton svelte components are working.